# Encryption scheme for a single bit CPA secure

Tags: chosen-plaintext-attack

I would love to get help figuring out how to prove the following theorem:

If there is an Encryption scheme for a single bit CPA secure then an Encryption scheme can be created along with a variable of bits which is also CPA secure.

I built a reduction, $Adversary$ for the single-bit scheme ($A$) that simulating the $Adversary$ of the variable of bits Encryption scheme ($A'$). $Adversary$ $A$ answers $A'$ Encryption queries so that he encrypts bit by bit and passes it back to him. When $A'$ outputs 2 messages $m_0$,$m_1$ from the same length to the challenger I am getting stuck.

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: To simplify you may consider a two-bit example. Hint: consider that $A'$ breaks variable length. How can one use this with the construction of a variable scheme from single bit CPA?

Comment: @kelaka Indeed, a two-bit example is a good start. But the full proof for this requires a hybrid argument.